# Apache redirection on https with or without "www"

Tags: dns, apache2

I have a problem on my dedicated server when it comes to redirecting the url.

My domain name is rented from OVH, and I installed Apache 2 on my dedicated server to manage my site.

I use let's encrypt to have the https protocol.

I would like that when I enter one of these addresses to access my site, I am redirected to the url "https://example.com":

- www.example.com: don't working "The security certificate of this website presents a problem".
- http://www.example.com: don't working "The security certificate of this website presents a problem".
- https://www.example.com: don't working "The security certificate of this website presents a problem".
- http://example.com: ok (redirect on https://example.com/)
- https://example.com: ok

Here is my apache configuration file for my domain in http (001-example.conf) :

[image]

And see the apache configuration file of my site for https (001-example-le-ssl.conf) :

[image]

On the side of the dns administration at ovh, here is the informations :

example.com. 0 A X.X.X.158

www.example.com. 0 A X.X.X.158

www.example.com. 0 TXT "3|welcome"

www.example.com. 0 TXT "l|fr"

example.com. 0 TXT "1|www.example.com"

Do you see something wrong with my setup?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate has to match the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) that the user is accessing, so if your certificate is only for `example.com`, then it will not cover `www.example.com`, the solution would be to remake the certificate and make the common name `example.com`, and add a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) to the certificate that is `www.example.com`, that way it will cover both FQDNs